# How to query Last inserted row for each group in oracle 10

Tags: oracle, join, query, oracle-10g

I have two tables about users where I want to join two tables and show the latest remarks of each user

bellow is table

[image]

I want to query the latest remarks for each user (1 remark per user)
bellow query I have written but it returns multiple remarks per user if date and time is the same for remarks

```
SELECT a.cust_id,b.remarks,b.contact_date,b.contact_time FROM customers a,(select * from customer_review
where (cust_id,contact_time,contact_date) in (select cust_id, max(contact_time),max(contact_date) from customer_review group by cust_id)
) b WHERE  a.cust_id=b.cust_id;
```

[image]

Please give any solution to query 1 remark per user
(Note: sorry I cannot alter column details if any)
Live link [Oracle Live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/i62hony8hpgu5j76mweyp8vte)

Comment: If the date & time is the same, which of the "same" ones is actually the "latest"?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ That is the problem ... I tried to take based on rownum or any one review based on insert order.. if date and time is same

Comment: A couple of other side observations.  It appears that CONTACT_DATE is a DATE and CONTACT_TIME is a TIMESTAMP. A DATE also includes time, to the second, and TIMESTAMP includes date and time, to the microsecond.  That makes CONTACT_DATE superfluous, as all of the information there is also in CONTACT_TIME.  Also, Oracle 10 has long, long been out of support. Well past time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is something like this with ROW_NUMBER() and `PARTITION`ing by cust_id and `ORDER`ing `BY contact_time DESC` so that the first one will be the latest. A fiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce9e888e54a49c3cdef0b35096f19544) - Oracle has microsecond precision, so it's very unlikely that you'll get simultaneous `remarks` by the same customer at the same time.

Create and populate customers table:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
  cust_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  cust_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1234, 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1235, 'Ram'); 
INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1236, 'Rahim');
```

Do the same for customer_review:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_review
(
  review_id VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  cust_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  remarks   VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  contact_date DATE NOT NULL,
  contact_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customer_review VALUES 
('NEW123', 1235, 'I am new user', 
TO_DATE('2019-10-27', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-27 06:10:13.278',  'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ms'));
INSERT INTO customer_review VALUES 
('CUST123', 1234, 'This is awesome product', 
TO_DATE('2019-10-26', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-26 11:15:15.123', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ms'));
INSERT INTO customer_review VALUES 
('CUST124', 1234, 'This is not good product. I have changed my mind now', 
TO_DATE('2019-10-27', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-27 16:25:15.567', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ms'));
INSERT INTO customer_review VALUES 
('CUST125', 1234, 'After upgrade, it is now working fine!', 
TO_DATE('2019-10-27', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-27 19:52:56.345', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ms'));
```

Then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT c.cust_name, t.cust_id, t.remarks FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY cust_id ASC, contact_time DESC) AS rn, 
    *
  FROM customer_review
) t
JOIN customers c
  ON t.cust_id = c.cust_id
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Result:

```
CUST_ID     REMARKS                                  CUST_NAME
   1234     After upgrade, it is now working fine!   John Doe
   1235     I am new user                            Ram
```

(after edit - these are now the correct answers - the remark by John Doe is his latest one as should be the case! Ram has only made one remark so by definition, it is the latest).

A few words of advice. You have your customers table with a plural and customer_review in the singular - pick one or the other and stick to it (you can search for "SQL style guide" and choose one you like. Personally, I recommend singular - a table is a set of things and therefore singular.

Next time you post, could you please include your table definitions as DDL text (`CREATE TABLE xxxx (field_1 type_1...);`) and your data as DML text (`INSERT INTO xxxx VALUES (val_1, val2...);`). [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) are a few reasons why posting screenshots is not the best approach for questions on DBA.SE. There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look?

Finally, I recommend that you use an integer for `review_id` - it makes sorting easier - otherwise you might be faced with having to use messy code like

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR('CUST1235',  5, LENGTH('CUST1235')) AS SMALLINT) AS no;
```

to extract the `INTEGER` from the `review_id` field.

It is possible to solve this problem using the Oracle [ROWNUM](http://psoug.org/definition/ROWNUM.htm) pseudo-column, but this is non-standard and it's better to develop good habits - and it will make your application more portable in the event that you/your company decide to do this. I hope this has helped - if it doesn't correspond to your requirements, please let me know and we can try and modify it. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

## Edit:

I finally got the Oracle fiddle working [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce9e888e54a49c3cdef0b35096f19544) - to microsecond precision.

Another point that struck me on rereading the question and my answer. You **don't need** to declared a `contact_date` field - it can be easily derived from the contact_time field. The data (date in this case) is therefore only stored in one field and one field only - which is conformant with RDBMS best practice.

There are two ways of doing this

- You can use the TO_DATE function when calling the table. Your table will now look like this (note `contact_date` is commented out. You then just call `TO_DATE(contact_time)` when you just want to get the date (example shown in the fiddle - table `customer_review_bis`).

---

```
CREATE TABLE customer_review_bis
(
  review_id VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  cust_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  remarks   VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  -- contact_date DATE NOT NULL,
  contact_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

- You can also use a `GENERATED AS` (aka `COMPUTED BY` or `CALCULATED`) column. These are very convenient and once defined, you have an effective guarantee that the date will always match the value in `contact_time`. This functionality used to be performed by `TRIGGER`s - it really is worth learning about these. The syntax `column_name [datatype] [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression) [VIRTUAL]` is described [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) (oracle-base is a super site). Your table definition now becomes (also shown in fiddle - `customer_review_ter`):

---

```
CREATE TABLE customer_review_ter
(
  review_id VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  cust_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  remarks   VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  contact_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  contact_date DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(contact_time)) VIRTUAL
);  -- you just treat contact_date as a normal field when you call it, in 
    -- exactly the same way as you did in your original example - table 
    -- customer_review (first one) in the fiddle.
```

If you choose the `GENERATED AS`, you have to slightly modify the `INSERT`statement by adding the fields that are updatable:

```
INSERT INTO customer_review_ter 
(review_id, cust_id, remarks, contact_time)
VALUES (.... data for specified fields ....);
```

Finally, as @EdStevens says, Oracle 10 is EOL (End of Life) - you really should think about upgrading!

Comment: I managed to get the Oracle fiddle working (microsecond) and also I've proposed two solutions to the issue of having a superfluous `contact_date` column.

Comment: Final revision - with the correct answers this time! Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for [pointing out my mistake](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52432512#52432512) - I think I got side-tracked with the replacement of the contact_date field... Ah well, these things happen! ;-)